# Cannot reinitialise DataTable when adding new script

Tags: javascript

I am getting the message

> DataTables warning: table id=dataTables-table_1 - Cannot reinitialise
>   DataTable.

after adding this code:

```
<?php
<!-- Internationalisation responsive table -->
<script>
$('#dataTables-table_1').DataTable( {
language: {
    processing:     "Verwerken...",
    search:         "Zoeken:",
    lengthMenu:     "Bekijk _MENU_ records",
    info:           "_START_ tot _END_ van _TOTAL_ records zichtbaar",
    infoEmpty:      "0 van 0 records",
    infoFiltered:   "(totaal _MAX_ records)",
    infoPostFix:    "",
    loadingRecords: "Records worden geladen...",
    zeroRecords:    "Er zijn geen records gevonden",
    emptyTable:     "De tabel is leeg",
    paginate: {
        first:      "Eerste",
        previous:   "Vorige",
        next:       "Volgende",
        last:       "Laaste"
    },
    aria: {
        sortAscending:  ": sorteer oplopend",
        sortDescending: ": sorteer aflopend"
    }
}
} );
</script>
?>
```

I think it is because this is already in the script:

```
<?php
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dataTables-table_1').DataTable({
            responsive: true
        });
    });
    </script>
?>
```

But I am not succeeding in combing them, everything I try I am loosing the first or second JS script. Please help me out.

Comment: Combining them should work, just add responsive: true to the first script and remove the second

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dataTables-table_1').DataTable( {
responsive: true,   //notice the comma
language: {
    processing:     "Verwerken...",
    search:         "Zoeken:",
    lengthMenu:     "Bekijk _MENU_ records",
    info:           "_START_ tot _END_ van _TOTAL_ records zichtbaar",
    infoEmpty:      "0 van 0 records",
    infoFiltered:   "(totaal _MAX_ records)",
    infoPostFix:    "",
    loadingRecords: "Records worden geladen...",
    zeroRecords:    "Er zijn geen records gevonden",
    emptyTable:     "De tabel is leeg",
    paginate: {
        first:      "Eerste",
        previous:   "Vorige",
        next:       "Volgende",
        last:       "Laaste"
    },
    aria: {
        sortAscending:  ": sorteer oplopend",
        sortDescending: ": sorteer aflopend"
    }
}
} );
```